# CakePHP - HasOne relationship retrieve null data

Tags: cakephp, belongs-to, has-one

I have this two classes:

```
class Client extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User',
        'plans' => array(
            'className'    => 'Plan',
            'foreignKey'   => 'plans_id'
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Order'
    );
}
```

}

```
class User extends AppModel{

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Rol' => array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'nombre')
    )
);

public $hasOne = array(
    'Client'
);
```

}

However cake retrieves this:

```
'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '32',
        'username' => 'test_admin',
        'correo_electronico' => 'a@d.com',
        'created' => '2013-06-09 19:58:18',
        'modified' => '2013-06-09 19:58:18',
        'esta_habilitado' => '1',
        'rol_id' => '1'
    ),
    'Rol' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'nombre' => 'Administrador'
    ),
    'Client' => array(
        'id' => null,
        'primer_nombre' => null,
        'segundo_nombre' => null,
        'primer_apellido' => null,
        'segundo_apellido' => null,
        'direccion' => null,
        'diudad' => null,
        'telefono' => null,
        'rating' => null,
        'created' => null,
        'modified' => null,
        'esta_habilitado' => null,
        'plans_id' => null,
        'user_id' => null
    )
```

Any ideas what's happening, I have check the foreign keys in the database and the id from the user corresponds to the user_id in the Client record

Comment: What is the relationship of all tables ? Relations are incorrect

Comment: How are you retrieving that array? With a simple find? No conditions? Could you add that code to your question?